# Android using tools:showIn with NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation

I want to preview my fragments inside the **layout editor** in the **navHostFragment** of another layout.
(The fragment is included in the navHostFragment's navigation garph)

I tried using **tools:showIn** and it didn't work. (I only get a blank display of my MainActivity layout)

Is there any way to work around this? or do I have to edit the MainActivity layout every time i want to preview the fragment where the NavHostFragment is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android` instead of `tools`. Because `tools` is actually used to display temporarily in the Preview.

Kindly [refer](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#:%7E:text=tools%3A%20instead%20of%20android%3A,-Intended%20for%3A%20%3CView&text=You%20can%20insert%20sample%20data,beforehand%2C%20in%20the%20layout%20preview.) to this Official Documentation to know it better.

Comment: Replacing `tools:showIn` with `android:showIn` won't do anything as its not even recognised as an attribute in the android schema.
I only want to preview my layout inside the navHostFragment. Usually we can use "tools:showIn", but it does not seem to work with when we intreduce android navigation components.